# In WEKA, J48, does setting the minNumObj to 1 make sense?

Tags: weka, rweka

When I was looking for explanation for minNumObj in WEKA, I came across this "the minimum number of instances per leaf is better thought of as the minimum amount of data separation per branching" and in this sense, I was wondering if setting the minNumObj to 1(one) would make sense or could it have a different meaning?